# What happens when you jokingly said 'I'm a nazir'?

Tags: halacha, nedarim-shevuot, speech-talking, intent-accident-purposely, nozir

If somebody gave you a bottle of wine, and you say I don't drink. They ask why, and you answer, jokingly 'I'm a nazir'. Did you take on a vow even though you only intended to joke?

Comment: Please do not do this

Comment: Why do you think one, who jokingly says he's a nazir, might have taken on a vow?

Comment: I wonder if in front of two witnesses we'd say דברים שבלב אינם דברים, and they can force him to keep nezirus. By oneself should definitely be fine, since didn't mean it.

Comment: @robev not sure that's true if it sounded like he was joking or even sounded likely that he could have been joking.

Comment: @MichaBerger I assume it's related to the complicated issue of קידושי שחוק

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Gray_Matter_III%2C_Family_Matters%2C_Frivolous_Wedding_Ceremonies.1?lang=bi

Comment: I think there were some teshuvos in the middle ages about idiots who said things like, I'll be a Nazir Shimshon if these are not the best grapes in the city! Don't be an idiot.

Comment: As mentioned above, there might be a question of עד אחד נאמן באיסורים, if so the listeners might believe him and force him to keep nezirus. But I don't know why he can't turn around and say, "I'm really not a nazir!" - that's also עד אחד. It's obvious that he was not making a vow.

Comment: @MichoelR עד אחד נאמן באיסורים does not apply here at all. Whether the listeners believe is irrelevant. I think the question is more was he stating a fact or accepting nezirus. If he says he was stating a fact, jokingly or not, he never accepted nezirus.

Comment: "I am a nazir" is not accepting nezirus; it does not imply a new acceptance. It could be that's the original question, but it's not the right question. It is, however, a statement of fact and therefore עד אחד נאמן באיסורים should apply. If I say, this meat is not kosher and then try to eat it, the Beis Din will try to stop me.

Comment: @MichoelR A witness can establish fact, but he cannot change someone's intent due to his belief.

Comment: @N.T. Could you explain what you mean? I don't understand how that is relevant, as he is speaking about his status. Presumably, according to his testimony, he must have said something that did make him a nazir in the past.

Comment: @MichoelR Witnesses could testify to his declaration, but only he knows if it was sincere.

Comment: @N.T. It doesn't matter if it's sincere. As I said, if a person says that something is not kosher, the Beis Din will try to stop him or anyone from eating it.

Comment: By kosher, there is no room for insincerity. By nazir there is.

Answer (score 1):

Cases like this are best handled by a qualified authority of Jewish Law so if this question actually applies to you I would recommend speaking with a rabbi.

The Shulchan Aruch rules ([YD 217:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.217.1?lang=bi)) that in terms of vows we follow the local speech patterns (**בנדרים אחר לשון בני אדם**) so it seems to me in this case the person was obviously joking and therefore we would not hold him to his words. See also [YD 218:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.218.1?lang=bi) which speaks more on this and also the commentaries there.

But as user [Heshy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11532/heshy) said in the comments, please do not do this. We see that taking vows over mitzvos are even more "binding" than vows about anything else ([Nedarim 8a](https://www.sefaria.org/Nedarim.8a.1?lang=bi), [YD 213:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.213.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Something I ponder on is whether or not a person who did take a vow of Nezirus nowadays if they would be able to perform Hataras Nedarim and be free from their vow. I honestly don't see why not. But that is a further question that cannot be answered here.

Answer (score 0):

Please **don't** try this.

The Mishna Nazir 11A says

מָזְגוּ לוֹ אֶת הַכּוֹס וְאָמַר הֲרֵינִי נָזִיר מִמֶּנּוּ הֲרֵי זֶה נָזִיר

*If a cup of wine was mixed for someone and he said "I am a nazir from it." He is a Nazir*

The Rambam Hilchos Nezirus 1:11 says further (also based on further in the Mishna)

מָזְגוּ לוֹ כּוֹס שֶׁל יַיִן וְנָתְנוּ לוֹ לִשְׁתּוֹת וְאָמַר הֲרֵינִי נָזִיר מִמֶּנּוּ הֲרֵי זֶה נָזִיר גָּמוּר. וְאִם הָיָה מַר נֶפֶשׁ אוֹ כּוֹעֵס אוֹ מִתְאַבֵּל וְהָיוּ מְבַקְּשִׁין מִמֶּנּוּ שֶׁיִּשְׁתֶּה כְּדֵי לְשַׁכֵּחַ עֲמָלוֹ וְאָמַר הֲרֵי זֶה נָזִיר מִמֶּנּוּ הֲרֵי זֶה אָסוּר בְּאוֹתוֹ הַכּוֹס בִּלְבַד וְאֵינוֹ נָזִיר. שֶׁלֹּא נִתְכַּוֵּן זֶה אֶלָּא שֶׁלֹּא יִשְׁתֶּה כּוֹס זֶה

*If a cup of wine was mixed  for a person and given to him to drink and he said: "I am a Nazir from it," he is a completely a Nazir If he was embittered , angry, or in mourning and the others were trying to have him drink to cause him to forget hs turmoil and he said: "I am a nazir from this [cup]," he is forbidden to drink only that cup, but he is not a nazir. Because  his intent was only that he would not drink that cup.*

Neither the Rambam not the Mishna make any allowances for saying I was joking. They both clearly say that you become a Nazir for saying it in this context. If it were only talking about someone who WANTED to be a Nazir then of course he would become one by saying so. Why would we think otherwise?

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question.

Comment: Neither the Rambam not the Mishna make any allowances for saying I was joking. They both clearly say that you become a Nazir for saying it. If it were only talking about someone who WANTED to be a Nazir then of course he would become one by saying so

Comment: I don't find that argument so compelling.

Answer (score -1):

In the specific case of the OP, there is a first reason he would not become a nazir:

He explained he *is* a nazir, he didn't say he *becomes* a nazir.

So, he lied. But he didn't received nezirus.

Comment: Hareini Nazir can translate into “I am a Nazir”. So not sure why you assume this isn’t a Neder. Perhaps it’sa neder havai and doesn’t work.

Comment: @Chatzkel הריני = *הרי* אני

Comment: Hareini is more "*here* I am". It is a transformation.